# I want to remove time stamp from date

Tags: apex

```
Date d = System.today().toStartOfMonth();
String newDate = d.format();
System.debug(Date.valueOf(newDate));
```

After removing time stamp again I need the date in Date format so I am converting string into date again but now it it again adding a timestamp while converting string into date

Answer (score 1):

`Date.valueOf(newDate)` => `Date.parse(newDate);`

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_date.htm

Comment: `DEBUG|2021-06-01 00:00:00` would appear even when using `Date.parse(newDate)`. The problem isn't the `Date`, it's `System.debug(Date)` that's confusing to some.

Comment: I misunderstood the question, I thought the problem was how to get a date from a date string, as the `Date.valueOf` requires a `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` format

Answer (score 0):

`System.debug(Date)` always shows the time portion, but it should always be 00:00:00.000. This is because of how Date and DateTime are implemented (Date is secretly a DateTime with the Time portion zeroed out). Whatever your use case, you can safely assume it will be correctly formatted however you use it. It's only when you debug it that you get the extra information.